# React with a event based communication

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to use React inside a [vscode webview panel](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview).  I'd consider myself decently component in react, but I'm used to communicating with the backend via http.

In this project, the vscode extension is essentially the server and all communication must be done by sending events between the two.

```
//vscode extension (server)

//send message to react app
panel.webview.postMessage({ command: 'refactor' });
//receive messages from react app
panel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(message => console.log(message))
```

```
//webview (react app)

//send message to extension
const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
vscode.postMessage({command: 'hello', text: 'world'});
//receive messages from extension
window.addEventListener('message', event => console.log(event))
```

My brain is struggling to determine the best way to setup 2-way communications.

For example, making a request from the webview to get data for a resource would typically that would look something like this:

```
public refresh = () => {
    this.setState({loading: true}, async () => {
       try{
         const item = await (await fetch('api/items/3')).json();
         this.setState({item});
       }catch(e){
         this.setState({loading: false, err: e});
       }
    })
}
```

But with the Event API this approach obviously doesn't work...

```
public refresh = () => {
   // could register a listener before sending and deactivate it after, but that seems wrong!
   vscode.postMessage({command: 'getItems', id: '3'});

}
```

I see some discussion about registering listeners in the `componentDidMount`, but since the event is a generic `message` then pretty much every component that communicates with server is going to be listening and then have to filter out what it cares about.

One idea at this point is to create a abstraction layer that allows the messages to be sent and the response awaited:

```
//track requests and wait for a response
const PENDING_REQUESTS = {};
function vscodeFetch(payload: any){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reqId = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(4)).join('-');
        vscode.postMessage({reqId, payload);
        PENDING_REQUESTS[reqId] = {resolve, reject};
    });

 }

 //handle update resolve/reject promises on response
 window.addEventListener('message', event => {
    const message = event.data;
    if(message.reqId){
        let promise = PENDING_REQUESTS[message.reqId];
        delete PENDING_REQUESTS[message.reqId];
        if(message.success){
            p.resolve(message.resp);
        }else{
            p.reject(message.err);
        }
    }
 });



let items = await vscodeFetch({command: 'getItems', data: {id: 3}});
```

but this kinda feels like I'd be inventing my own protocol (sounds simple until you start considering exceptional behavior like timeouts)!

Comment: Stepped away to get coffee and it clicked! Redux would work wonderfully with this setup.  

Sometimes it takes writing a dissertation on stackoverflow just to wrap your brain around the problem

Comment: @NSjonal Hey, I know it's been 4 years already, but can you share some details on adding Redux to VSCode extension?

Comment: @SergeiKlinov it's been a while but the setup was pretty straight forward...

Setup redux in your react vscode web view just as you normally would.  Add a window event listener (similar to what is shown above) at the root of the application that just  `dispatches` redux events in response to `vscode.postMessage` (or other events).

I haven't checked the vscode extension API in some time; there may be a simpler approach...

Comment: Cool, thanks for the response - I'll try that. For some reason event listeners didn't work for me now, but maybe I did something wrong and just need to debug a bit. Cheers!

Comment: Turns out I actually went through the trouble of setting up a demo project for this lol.   I'm sure it's very out of date, but that should give you a better idea of exactly how I got it to work...

https://github.com/ChuckJonas/vscode-react-redux-webview-example

Comment: Thanks, I think I've checked out that repo during my research. But I had a separate issue of multiple webpack builds that created separate scopes of the store and the whole thing together didn't work properly. But I surely get the idea and it's somewhat very similar to what I had.