# How to make acquireVsCodeApi available in vscode webview [React]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webview, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to develop a new extension for vscode based on `Webview` but I am running into problems with posting messages from client to extension. As a starter, I used [this repo](https://github.com/rebornix/vscode-webview-react) and I am following these [steps from Microsoft](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#passing-messages-from-a-webview-to-an-extension).

As you can see in the example we have:

```
(function() {
            const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
```

My problem is that in my react app the `acquireVsCodeApi` is like it doesn't exist. I tried multiple ways eg. in `componentDidMount` lifecycle but no luck.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382843/react-with-a-event-based-communication) seems to be able to run it but parts of his app are missing so is not clear to me.

Does anyone have an idea of how to use `acquireVsCodeApi()` with React or a code snippet that can help?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so first you need to assign it into a variable in webview content in a script eg:
https://github.com/shinhwagk/vscode-note/blob/be2aabf2812a9b6200be971425535024440dbd88/src/panel/notesPanelView.ts#L32

and then in typescript, it has to be an interface

```
interface vscode {
    postMessage(message: any): void;
}

declare const vscode: vscode;

const addCategory = () => () => vscode.postMessage({ command: 'add-category' });
```

Solution came from here: https://github.com/shinhwagk/vscode-note/blob/be2aabf2812a9b6200be971425535024440dbd88/src/webview/index.tsx#L10

Comment: Why do you need the JS vscode API in your TS code? You have direct access to the entire vscode API. The aquisition via that function is only made for JS script code you load into a webview.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Unseen's answer, what i did is create a `global.d.ts` file, and declare vscode type there.

```
type VSCode = {
  postMessage(message: any): void;
  getState(): any;
  setState(state: any): void;
};

declare const vscode: VSCode;
```

In this case you can access vscode in any file. Example: https://github.com/hacker0limbo/vscode-webview-react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/global.d.ts

Answer (score 2):

### Webpack + NPM version

> This NPM version uses two packages: `vscode-webview` and `@types/vscode-webview`. The `@types/vscode-webview` is reasonably recent, but `vscode-webview` has been abandoned in an immature state. While the code 'webpack's ok, it is somewhat dubious.

Your repository uses typescript, and so you can install a type declaration from npm to allow your typescript checker to determine the correct interface for the vscode api.

A type declaration file is available for vscode-webview on npm.:
`npm install @types/vscode-webview`

Then, in your code, you would put in your imports:

```
import "vscode-webview"
```

This is a little different from the usual `import * from "vscode-webview"` as the author has used a global scoped declare to match the globally scoped `acquireVsCodeApi` function.

Link on npm: [@types/vscode-webview] https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vscode-webview

### To avoid the dubious package:

Copy the contents of `@types/vscode-webview` into a local file, and point your imports at your local file.

Comment: Please explain why it is most correct. Maybe by pointing out what less correct options you compare to and explain how they are less correct. Maybe describe the benefits povided by being more correct. How can you be sure that there are no more correct options? Please consider taking the [tour] and reading [answer].

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33532911)

Answer (score 0):

The function `acquireVsCodeApi()` will be by default available when the app runs inside vs code. But you may get a ts error or a eslint error while compiling React or any other library. Just ignore them with ts ignore or es lint disable comments and then proceed with your code.

```
function App {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
    ...
}

// or

function App {
    // @ts-ignore
    const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
    ...
}
```